# dropdownlist displays wrong item after refreshing page in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, drop-down-menu, refresh

I have a dropdownlist inside updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelTables" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTournamnets" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnIndexChanged"
                    runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Something1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Something2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<asp:/UpdatePanel>
```

When I select some item, dropdown does postback and content inside updatepanel is changed. When I refresh the page (using f5), is loaded content which corresponds to item with index=0, but dropdownlist displays item which was before refreshing and if I now select first item postback does not occur.  The problem is only in Firefox.

Comment: OK, you've determined that the problem is on the client, particularly in FF5. So why on earth are you showing us the server-side code and NOT YOUR HTML?!?!?!

Comment: html is ok. When refresh page with ctrl+f5 everything works fine

Comment: You are refreshing the page with F5, the contents of the whole page should be "reset" in this case. That is an expected behaviour when the page loads and you have not saved them somewhere else. I've tested your sample in FF, and the postback for the dropdown still works for me after I refresh the page. Post some code to replicate your problem better.

Comment: the problem is when I select "Something2" and refresh the page, SelectedValue is 1, but it still display "Something2", must be "Something1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to reset that dropdown upon the refresh on FF then do it this way:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetddp(){
    var ddl=document.getElementById('DropDownListTournamnets');
    ddl.options[0].selected=true;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="resetddp();">
<!--The rest of your code here-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#content_ProjectName option[value='1']").prop("selected", true);
});
```

To show the first item of the dropdown 
`ProjectName.ClearSelection();`
Put this code in your design page to work on all browsers and also put this on code behind on page load